# Need to add 8080 in the domain name for my web app to work

Tags: apache, url, port, tomcat6

I have a Java EE application which uses Tomcat 6 as the server. I have managed to deploy it on linode, however to access my web application I need to hit www.xyz.com:8080, instead of just www.xyz.com (where xyz.com is my domain).

If I just hit www.xyz.com, I get the entire directory listing of my application.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Hi Maxim, I have the same problem! I changed the server.xml file and changed the `port=8080` to `port=80` but I get a 404 error. What am I doing wrong? How did you fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your application server is listening for HTTP requests on port 8080. Change its configuration to listen to the default port for HTTP, which is port 80.